# Spit IObservable<T> exceptions in a separate IObservable<Exception> and continue normally

Tags: system.reactive

I have an hot `IObservable<T>` which may throw an exception. However, I would like to continue with it. I think I could use `Retry` operator for that. However, it would be great if I can also listen to any error in `IObservable<T>` through a separate `IObservable<Exception>`. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case is significantly more simplified in that you have a hot observable.

`OnError` is a notification outside your value stream, so we could *materialize* the notifications to retrieve the error. This still causes the tear-down of the stream with an `OnCompleted`, so you'll need to re-subscribe with `Repeat`.

```
var exceptions =
    source
        .Materialize()
        .Where(notif => notif.Kind == NotificationKind.OnError)
        .Select(notif => notif.Exception)
        .Repeat();
```

**Note**

If you're using a `Subject<T>` for your hot observable, you might run into the usual problem of re-subbing a subject. A subject will replay its `OnError` or `OnCompleted` notifications for every new observer.

```
var source = new Subject<int>();            
source.OnNext(1);
source.OnError(new Exception());
source.Subscribe(
        i => Console.WriteLine(i), 
        ex => Console.WriteLine("Still got exception after the throw")
);
```

In this case your exception stream will go into an infinite re-subscription loop.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your question violates [the observable contract](http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html):

> An Observable may make zero or more OnNext notifications, each representing a single emitted item, and it may then follow those emission notifications by either an OnCompleted or an OnError notification, but not both. **Upon issuing an OnCompleted or OnError notification, it may not thereafter issue any further notifications.** *(emphasis mine)*

In other words, after your hot `IObservable<T>` throws an exception, the observable is ended. The observable of exceptions that comes out of that has a max count of one.

If you want to support a scenario where you re-start an observable after an exception, you're producing a stream of observables, or `IObservable<IObservable<T>>`. To work with that, here's a code sample:

```
var source = new Subject<Subject<int>>();

var exceptionStream = source
    .SelectMany(o => o.Materialize())
    .Where(n => n.Kind == NotificationKind.OnError)
    .Select(n => n.Exception);

var itemStream = source
    .SelectMany(o => o.Materialize())
    .Where(n => n.Kind == NotificationKind.OnNext)
    .Select(n => n.Value);

var items = new List<int>();
var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
itemStream.Subscribe(i => items.Add(i));
exceptionStream.Subscribe(e => exceptions.Add(e));

var currentSubject = new Subject<int>();
source.OnNext(currentSubject);

currentSubject.OnNext(1);
currentSubject.OnNext(2);
currentSubject.OnNext(3);
currentSubject.OnError(new Exception("First error"));

var currentSubject2 = new Subject<int>();
source.OnNext(currentSubject2);

currentSubject2.OnNext(4);
currentSubject2.OnNext(5);
currentSubject2.OnNext(6);
currentSubject2.OnError(new Exception("Second error"));

items.Dump(); //Linqpad
exceptions.Dump(); //Linqpad
```